# How do I fix the current line color using solarized vim dark mode using Termdebug?

Tags: vim, gdb, vim-plugin, color-scheme, vim-syntax-highlighting

I'm using solarized with vim and when I'm debugging (using Termdebug), the current execution line is missing:

[image]

I've been working around the issue by switching to light mode:

[image]

If I go back to dark, then I have a cursor color :

[image]

It is not a good color though. The text is hardly readable.

What might be the problem? Can I fix it or are there any workarounds?

I'm using gnome terminal 3.28.2 and am using the solarized color scheme for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solarized hasn't been updated in 12 years. Meanwhile, a lot happened in Vim that Solarized doesn't support. Like the `TermDebug` feature that comes with two new highlight groups: `debugPC` and `debugBreakpoint`.

- Because your chosen colorscheme ignores them, you get the default styling, which may or may not work.
- Because your chosen colorscheme is abandonware, it didn't magically improve in 12 years. It is at least as bad as it ever was, and it has always been the worst. This might explain that weird behavior on dark > light > dark.
- Because your chosen colorscheme is written in a user-hostile way, it is harder than necessary to modify it to suit your needs.

If you *really* want to keep using Solarized, I would recommend you drop the hopelessly broken original in favor of a *hackable* competently made and maintained interpretation like [solarized8](https://github.com/lifepillar/vim-solarized8).

Comment: I'm not attached to solarized. What's another popular option that's still maintained?

Comment: We recently remade all the built-in colorschemes and also added a few new ones that could catch your fancy: `habamax`, `lunaperche`, `quiet`, `retrobox`, `sorbet`, `wildcharm`, and `zaibatsu`.